# Wordpress revolution slider used on HTML site

Tags: html, css, plugins, wordpress

is there a way to use wordpress Revolution Slider on site without wordpress (it means just HTML and CSS site)?
I have tried to look for some JS but there is so many JS scripts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [jQuery version](http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-jquery-plugin/2580848), and [here](http://previous.themepunch.com/revolution4-jquery/liveguide/01.Sample-Boxed.html) some documentation.

Comment: But this option isn't free. Have to purchase the jquery version also.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the WordPress plugin try this [export to HTML](https://www.themepunch.com/faq/export-for-html-usage-with-5-0/) feature.

Once you extract the zip, rename slider.html to slider.php & include it on any page

```
    <?php include 'slider.php'; ?>
```